# Unable to mount partition on boot

Tags: boot, disk-management

I have installed elementary OS and Windows 10 alongside. after dividing a partition into two from Windows side, seems like elementary OS unable to mount the partitions on booting. It shows following error message.

```
disk drive for mnt/50FE*** is not ready yet or not present. continue to wait ...
```

is it possible to manually un-mount `50FE***` partition (after I edit the partition `50FE***` partition is not available anymore)

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution,

I have manually edited the FSTAB file (etc/fstab). FSTAB contains all the details regarding the mount-points including auto-mount drivers in the boot-up.
so delete the line corresponding to the missing disk

here is my FSTAB file

```
    # /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=09642702-1d8e-41b8-897f-98079b8609e4 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /home was on /dev/sda7 during installation
UUID=7554c61b-b8c9-45af-b5df-199670167a04 /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=a54e0244-c77d-4672-9df9-2840924e0c94 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/50FEFBC9FEFBA4FE /mnt/50FEFBC9FEFBA4FE auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,x-udisks-auth,x-gvfs-name=Windows%2010 0 0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/3C7404F67404B4A5 /mnt/3C7404F67404B4A5 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,x-udisks-auth,x-gvfs-name=Data 0 0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/01D1953299EF8656 /mnt/01D1953299EF8656 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,x-udisks-auth,x-gvfs-name=Windows 0 0
```

in my case i have deleted

> /dev/disk/by-uuid/50FEFBC9FEFBA4FE /mnt/50FEFBC9FEFBA4FE auto
>   nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,x-udisks-auth,x-gvfs-name=Windows%2010
>   0 0

hope this will help to someone

Cheers !

Answer (score 0):

Boot Windows 10 and then reboot into elementary OS.This will reboot Windows without hybrid shutdown and you should be able to mount the partiton

Comment: How does this help to get rid of the error message ?

Comment: It allows you to mount partition from Linux. You can also disable hybrid shutdown if you want a permanent solution

Comment: I'm new to linux and still not clear your answer,

Comment: See http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4189-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-10-a.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply but after i enabled "Fast Start up" eOS gives me more error messages. eOS can't find my other partitions too. maybe you misunderstood my problem

Comment: Then disable it